# Activeadmin polymorphic association, paperclip attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin for `car` resource and multiple attachments are not entering into records, `car` records are created successfully but on creation it did not contain attachment. I have two models 'Attachment', `models/attachment.rb`

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

And 
and my `model/car.rb` contains following code

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :attachments, as: :imageable
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

and in my `app/admin/car.rb` I have following code for multiple attachment.

```
form do |f|
  f.input :make
  f.input :model
  f.input :color
  f.input :engine_type
  f.input :description
  f.has_many :attachments do |attachment|
    attachment.input :attachment, :as => :file
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Can anybody please explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: Can show your permit_params for your `admin/car.rb`?

Comment: What does the log file say when you attempt to save/create the record?

Answer (score 0):

I think your input field should be :avatar instead of :attachment

So, it should look like

```
f.has_many :attachments do |attachment|
  attachment.input :avatar, :as => :file
end
```

Comment: also form needs to be multipart 

`form multipart: true do |f|`